# Call to a member function createElement() on a non-object in php

Tags: php, xml

i would like to create xml file something like that using XML DOM Parser

```
<dict>
<key>outlineThickness</key>     <real>0.0</real>
<key>repeat</key>       <false />
<key>rotation</key>     <string>no</string>
</dict>
```

but my code show me errors 
Notice: Undefined variable: dom in C:\wamp\www\iwatermark\xmlapi\xmlapi.php on line 18
Fatal error: Call to a member function createElement() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\iwatermark\xmlapi\xmlapi.php on line 18.

this is what i write

```
<?php

class XMLApi
{
    private $dom = null;
    private $root = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
        $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;

        $root = $dom->createElement("dict");
        $dom->appendChild($root);
    }

    public function createNode($keyname, $keytext, $valuename, $valuetext)
    {   
        $item = $dom->createElement($keyname);
        $root->appendChild($item);

        // create text node
        $text = $dom->createTextNode($keytext);
        $item->appendChild($text);

        if($valuename == "true" || $valuename == "false")
        {
            $item = $dom->createElement($valuename);
            $root->appendChild($item);
        }
        else
        {
            $item = $dom->createElement($valuename);
            $root->appendChild($item);

            // create text node
            $text = $dom->createTextNode($valuetext);
            $item->appendChild($text);
        }
        // create child element


    }

    public function ending()
    {
        $dom->save("test01.xml");
    }
}





$obj = new XMLApi();
$obj->createNode("key","outlineThickness","real","0.0");
$obj->createNode("key","repeat","false","");
$obj->createNode("key","rotation","string","no");
$obj->ending();




header("Location: "."test01.xml");

?>
```

Comment: use `$this->dom` instead of `$dom` inside createNode function as in the whole class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$this->dom` when accessing a class variable from inside the class.

Comment: getting syntax error on this $item = this->dom->createElement($keyname);

Comment: `$this` not `this`. Mind the `$` as we are talking about PHP, isn't it?